# Is there a way to extend these two disk partitions in Windows 10? And should I be worried that recovery partitions are 100% full?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, recovery-partition

See my disk management below from my Windows 10 machine. I am a newbie with disk management, so please be gentle.

1. Should I be concerned that the two recovery partitions are at 100%?
2. Is there an easy way to extend the 499MB partition to be a gig (1,024MB) in size and then extend the "E:" drive into the remaining space?

Drive letter E is completely empty at the moment, so I'm not concerned if it has to be blown away and reinstated.

If it is, I'd like to play it safe and extend the "C:" drive by another 30GB. Then whatever's left assign 1GB to the recovery partition and give drive "E" whatever space is left.

I am not given any options on the 499MB Recovery Partition when I right-click on it other than "help". Notice that it's not even denoted as a "file system" type.

Thank you!

**EDIT:** thank you to @Daniel B for pointing out how I read the DiskManager wrong. Those partitions are 100% *FREE*, not *FULL*. Doh. So question 1 is redundant although I am curious why they're not formatted with a file system?

[image]

Comment: Why so many disks and partitions?  You seem to be fragmenting your space so as to have less. Do not spend time on the Recovery or UEFI partitions  - nothing there to do or manage. Then I I were you I would consolidate your drive space.

Comment: I didn't create the 100MB or 499MB partitions; I currently don't need more than 300GB for the OS C:, so what I did was split that drive into two. The 30GB I took from drive E to try and expand the 499MB Recovery partition to no avail. So all up at most there were 4 partitions on that drive, of which I did not create two of them. At most I figured there were 3 partitions (the 100MB created by default). That's not unreasonable to me.

Comment: It is not at all unreasonable. I have just done it differently. Ignore UEFI and Recovery (they are what they are), 1 TB of space divided into Used and Free. 6 machines on board hat expand and contract as needed. Very little time spent on disk management (run Cleanup weekly).

Comment: They are actually marked as 100% _free_, by the way. Probably because they’re not mounted.

Comment: Thank you @DanielB as I completely misread that obviously! My post has been updated with your correction.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely normal and no reason for concern that EFI and recovery partitions are 100% full, since no new files are going to be created there.

Partitions cannot be extended at the beginning, only at the end. That is, your 499MB recovery partition cannot be extended into the unallocated space (and, as I said, doesn't need to) but your E: partition can.

The Windows disk management tool cannot move partitions, but third party tools like GParted can. So if you had a need to extend the 499MB partition anyway, you could use GParted to move it left by the needed amount and then extend it at the end. Also, if you had a need to preserve the E: partition but extend the C: partition, you could use GParted to move the E: partition right by the needed amount and then extend the C: partition.